# I want to add a specific number to a specific part of my script in python without using repetitive numbers in the sequence

Tags: python, list, sequence

I can't seem to find a way to add a specific number to a given part of my code I am able to generate sequential numbers from 1- any number but i can't seem to figure out how to assign a specific number such as 5,712, 910, to each given line. Below is the code i have in terms of sequential numbers. its coded in python2. Here is what it looks like when doing 5 instances, ultimately i need to be able to change the 1,2,3,4,5 to specific numbers that I want to use instead of random or sequential. Any help would be appreciated! Below is also my code. For example: if i needed numbers such as 516, 813,901,831,and 194 how would i assign those values to each given string separately

```
amount = int(raw_input("How many instances do you want to create?\t"))
vip_ = raw_input("which country?\t").lower()

baseproxy = "hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_%s-vip-%d:password"

for x in range(0, 5):
    print baseproxy %(vip_,x+1)

hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-1:password
hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-2:password
hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-3:password
hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-4:password
hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-5:password
```

Comment: Why don't you just store the numbers you want to assign in a predefined list and then insert them into the string as you iterate through a for loop?

Comment: thanks a lot really appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

`range(0, 5)` is really just creating a generator that looks like `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]` under the hood.

If you wanted to create strings for a list of specific numbers you can just iterate over a specific list

```
my_numbers = [516, 813, 901, 831, 194]
for number in my_numbers:
    print baseproxy % (vip_, number)

hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-516:password
hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-813:password
hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-901:password
hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-831:password
hello.test.io:22225:testing-customer-username-zone-vip_ca-vip-194:password
```

If you want to allow the user to specify the number for each instance, you could try something like this

```
my_numbers = []
amount = int(raw_input("How many instances do you want to create?\t"))
for i, instance in enumerate(amount):
    my_numbers.append(int(raw_input("What is the number for instance %s?" % i+1)))
...
```

Comment: You can also get those numbers using `raw_input`.